# Construction of a triangle with the center of the circumscribed circle and the orthocenter

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct a triangle $ABC$ given that we have point $A$, and point $O$ i.e., the center of the circumscribed circle and the orthocenter?

Comment: Join $A$ with $H$ (the orthocenter) with a line $h_A$. Draw a line $m_A$ through $O$ parallel to $h_A$. Take the midpoint $E_A$ of $AH$ and draw a circle $c$ with center $N$ (the midpoint of $OH$) and passing through $E_A$. The point of intersection of $m_A$ and $c$ on the other side of $A$ is the midpoint $O_A$ of the side $BC$. The point of intersection of $h_A$ and $c$ the base $H_A$ of the altitude from $A$. Then drawing the line $H_A$ to $O_A$ and interecting it with the circumcircle gives you $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Guide yourself with [the drawing in  this link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Euler_line). Even though it has many lines that we don't need.The construction is just getting the points of the [Nine-point circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle) that are on the side $BC$.